# Chargent for Salesforce - Customizing and expanding it's usefulness

Tags: apex, administration, custom-object

Does anyone know of any resources to help utilize **Chargent** in Salesforce?  Specifically:

- Billing people on a specific schedule without human intervention
- Billing multiple down payments on a specific schedule before monthly billing starts
- Storing multiple credit cards for easy access-reuse when customers request payment using a specific previously-given card

There is more, but ultimately, we want to heavily customize this item so that there is very little human interaction once a sale is made and initial settings have been stored.  It MAY end up requiring Apex, but I'm hopeful we can limit this to Workflows and Custom Objects+Fields (we would be using it in it's Opportunity mode since we used Closed Won Opps for our sales).

Thanks for any insights or leads to those who may specialize in Chargent.  If someone feels this is not clearly enough a proper item to be posting to this forum, please let me know where you think it would be more appropriate.  I am trying to avoid simply hiring a random developer to do this for us, and find personnel/guides/etc that specifically work with Chargent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go to [AppFrontier's website](http://www.appfrontier.com/support.html) and ask them for a referral. They state on their website that they offer implementation services for "complex Salesforce workflows" or integration. If they're the same group I worked with years ago when implementing Chargent in a highly customized Salesforce environment, they're excellent at what they do.

Here's what their support page says:

> For assistance with more complex Salesforce workflows, or to integrate Chargent with other business processes or external systems, AppFrontier works with a number of consulting partners.
>
> Please [Contact Us](http://www.appfrontier.com/contact.html) for a referral.

There's also contact information on their [AppExchange page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016jrcEAA).

Comment: We moved far beyond ever using chargent, but I accept this answer (now, so far later, sorry) as it's a good answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @AMM - Curious what you mean by "far beyond ever using Chargent" - Disclaimer I am affiliated with Chargent but the developer in me loves all kinds of solutions. If you can summarize I would love to hear it.

Comment: Two fold:  My then-company ended up doing something highly customized / developed specific for them, and they are my "then" company.  ;-)  My current company is in the middle of initial integration of SF / changeover from existing Synergy system.  We not even looking at a Chargent type solution "yet", possibly wave 2 after initial deployment.